# display binary strings without consecutive 1’s

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

How can i modify the below backtracking code which is used to display all the combinations of N digit binary number *to* display binary number which doesn't have consecutive 1's?
example:
Input:  N = 2
Output: 3
// The 3 strings are 00, 01, 10

Input: N = 3
Output: 5
// The 5 strings are 000, 001, 010, 100, 101

```
#include <stdio.h>

char target[100];
void foo(int size, int count)
{
    if (count > size)
        return;
    if (count == size) {
        target[count] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", target);
        return;
    }
    if (count < size) {
        target[count] = '1';
        foo(size, count+1);
    }
    target[count] = '0';
    foo(size, count+1);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    foo(n, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: modify to NOT display consecutive 1's as shown in example.
for N=3: 000, 001, 010, 100, 101

Comment: Ah, got it! Erasing previous comments....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't place a '1' if the previous position is also '1'. For example:

```
if (count == 0 || target[count-1] != '1') {
    target[count] = '1';
    foo(size, count+1);
}
```

Comment: thanks and it worked like a charm. I remember i did try this but somehow i overlooked the result and thought it will not work. Thanks.